# Can I preview the new profile page on another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, profile-page

I would like to see what the new profile page looks like on Stack Overflow. Do I just have to wait until it's done, or can I preview it now?

Comment: Code is first changed on this site for test; when they are ready, they change the code for all the other sites. I guess there is a practical reason to do so; it is not a matter of preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will have to wait till it is launched on Stack Overflow.

We hope to finish the work in the next couple of weeks and start launching it on sites that have gone through .less refactoring.

Answer (score -1):

<s>You can't yet, at least because CSS for it only exist on MSE (you *could* apply SO stylesheet for profile page on MSE, buy you'll get nothing interesting).</s>

You can look how your MSE profile page looks like on Stack Overflow by its stylesheet.

Just paste this javascript in your address bar and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
javascript:var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {var link = links[i];if(link.rel === "stylesheet") {link.href = "/content/stackoverflow/all.css";break;}}
```

Comment: When I tried that javascript, nothing happened.

Comment: @tbodt It works for me; did you go to the profile tab? Also, this script applies another stylesheet which may take a while to load.

Comment: Go to the profile tab? I can't see a profile tab on Stack Overflow, even when I run this.

Comment: @tbodt oh no. You misunderstood me or I did you. This script is needed to show you *design* of the new profile page on Stack Overflow. As this page *was only launched* on MSE, it is avaliable only there. My script just applies the SO style to your MSE profile page.

Comment: Please note: if you paste `javascript:` it will be stripped out of the url by chrome.